# What are the primary considerations when trekking across the Olympic National Park, Greece including a summit of Mount Olympus?

Tags: hiking, trekking, walking, europe

I am planning to make a solo traverse of the Olympic National Park in Greece, including a summit of Mount Olympus.

I am a former soldier and team medic with considerable experience in the outdoors, although none of it on the Greek peninsula.

What conditions would affect my success in the month of June and what considerations might I  possibly overlook?

Comment: Aren't you worried about Zeus taking offense? :)

Comment: Haha exactly - but it was more an awareness of any bears, wolves etc.

Comment: I don't think there are bears there. The most you will find is wolves. And they don't come for humans. If you stick to the known trails, animals typically avoid those due to frequent human presence. I had trekked along the Vikos gorge solo in winter. So Olympic National Park should be fairly doable in summer. Just make sure people know you are going in. And carry a stout stick with you. In any case, there will be other people doing the route in summer, so you won't be all that alone.